# Logistic regression (Verhulst's logic equation)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha, wolfram-language

I need to build 2 graphics:

1. using logistic regression model
2. using the same model but with Allee effect

I tried using this [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3CWP.png) in WolframAlpha
but it doesn't show any diagram, and looks like I do something wrong.

So I have 2 questions:

1. How should I write the logistic regression equation including Allee effect?
2. How should I write these formulas in WolframAlfa so that I can see the diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Re. your expression

[image]

You could plot the following for various values of `r`, `k` and `p0`

```
(E^(r t) k p0)/(k - p0 + E^(r t) p0)
```

Obtained from

[image]

With reference to https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticEquation.html